# How to solve $y'=e^{\frac{xy'}y}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following equation?

$$y'=e^{\frac{xy'}y}$$

We must find a common solution.

Comment: Are you sure the left hand side is $y'$, not $y$?

Comment: Yes, it is written in the job.

Comment: This is first order nonlinear ODE

Comment: Use wolfram alpha to solve. You get the solution as $y=-e^{\left(c_1-e^{c_{_1}}x\right)}$ . Link is [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%3De%5E%28xy%27%2Fy%29+%2C&x=6&y=7)

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=e^{xy'/y}$$
$$y\ln(y')=xy'$$

1. Substitute $y=e^{Ax+C}$ to get
   $$e^{Ax+C}\ln(Ae^{Ax+C})=xAe^{Ax+C}$$
   $$\ln(Ae^{Ax+C})=Ax$$
   $$Ae^{Ax}e^C=e^{Ax}$$
   $$Ae^C=1$$
   $$A=e^{-C}$$
   So the solution is $$y=e^{e^{-C}x+C}$$
2. Substitute $y=-e^{Ax+C}$ and follow steps from above to get the solution $$y=-e^{-e^{-C}x+C}$$

Be aware that by substitutions we are *not* guaranteed to find *all* solutions.

Comment: $-e^{-x}$ is a solution as well. In general, why can you substitute $y=e^{Ax+C}$? You are missing solutions which are not of this form.

Comment: @Wojowu by substitution you are not guaranteed to find all solutions

Comment: This is precisely my point.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=e^{\frac{xy'}{y}}$$
Let : $u=\frac{xy'}{y}$ so, $y'=\frac{yu}{x}$
$$\frac{yu}{x}=e^u$$
$$y=x\frac{e^u}{u}$$
$$y'=\frac{e^u}{u}+x\frac{e^u}{u}u'-x\frac{e^u}{u^2}u'=e^u$$
This allows to eliminate $e^u$
$$\frac{1}{u}+x\frac{1}{u}u'-x\frac{1}{u^2}u'=1$$
$$x(u-1)u'=u^2-u=(u-1)u$$
A particular solution is $u=1$ and the trivial solution $y=x\frac{e^1}{1}=ex$

General case $u\neq 1$ :
$$xu'=u$$
$$u=cx$$
Then, the general solution :
$$y=x\frac{e^u}{u}=x\frac{e^{cx}}{cx}$$
$$y=\frac{e^{cx}}{c}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)=e^{\frac{xy'(x)}{y(x)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $y(x)=xv(x)$, which gives $y'(x)=v(x)+xv'(x)$:

---

$$xv'(x)+v(x)=e^{\frac{xv'(x)+v(x)}{v(x)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xv'(x)+v(x)=e^{1+\frac{xv'(x)}{v(x)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$v'(x)=\frac{-v(x)-\text{W}\left(-\frac{1}{v(x)}\right)v(x)}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{v'(x)}{-v(x)-\text{W}\left(-\frac{1}{v(x)}\right)v(x)}=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{v'(x)}{-v(x)-\text{W}\left(-\frac{1}{v(x)}\right)v(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left|\text{W}\left(-\frac{1}{v(x)}\right)\right|=\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$v(x)=-\frac{e^{-e^{\text{C}}x-\text{C}}}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=-e^{-e^{\text{C}}x-\text{C}}$$